# Hide a section based on the select box

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show different sections based on what option is selected, and when no option is selected I need them both to hide.

In HTML I have,

```
<label for = "registration_select"></label>
<select id = "registration_selection name = "registration">
     <option value = "select"> ---Select--- </option>
     <option value = "option1"> Option A </option>
     <option value = "option2"> Option B </option>
</select>

<section id = "show_option_A"></section>
<section id = "show_option_B"></section>
```

And in JavaScript I have

```
const register = document.querySelector("#registration");
const optionA = document.querySelector("#show_option_A");
const optionB = documnt.querySelctor("#show_option_B");

function determineClass(){
     if(register === "select"){
          optionA.style.display = "none";
          optionB.style.display = "none";
     }else if(register === option1){
          optionA.style.display = "block";
          optionB.style.display = "none";
     }else{
          optionA.style.display = "none";
          optionB.style.display = "block";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

the select element:

```
<select id = "registration_selection" onchange="determineClass(this)" name = "registration">
 <option value = "select"> ---Select--- </option>
 <option value = "option1"> Option A </option>
 <option value = "option2"> Option B </option>
</select>
```

the javascript:

```
const optionA = document.querySelector("#show_option_A");
const optionB = documnt.querySelctor("#show_option_B");

function determineClass(e){
var register = e.value
     if(register === "select"){
          optionA.style.display = "none";
          optionB.style.display = "none";
     }else if(register === option1){
          optionA.style.display = "block";
          optionB.style.display = "none";
     }else{
          optionA.style.display = "none";
          optionB.style.display = "block";
     }
}
```

immediately when the select element is change it will invoke the determineClass function then it will do the checking with the select element value, hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You've missed alot of things, missspelling and other things.

`querySelctor` is `querySelector`
`documnt` is `document`

`document.querySelector("#registration")` is trying to find registration by id but there's no id registration... it's id is `registration_selection`

At `registration_selection` you forgot to put quotes to close id define.

And here's working version:

```js
const register = document.querySelector("#registration_selection");
const optionA = document.querySelector("#show_option_A");
const optionB = document.querySelector("#show_option_B");

register.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (register.value === "option1") {
      optionA.style.display = "block";
      optionB.style.display = "none";
      }
  else if (register.value === "option2") {
          optionA.style.display = "none";
          optionB.style.display = "block";
          }
  else {
      optionA.style.display = "none";
      optionB.style.display = "none";
      }
});
```

```html
<label for="registration_select"></label>
<select id="registration_selection" name="registration">
     <option value = "select"> ---Select--- </option>
     <option value = "option1"> Option A </option>
     <option value = "option2"> Option B </option>
</select>

<section id = "show_option_A" style="display: none;">A</section>
<section id = "show_option_B" style="display: none;">B</section>
```